# How do I stop Mac PowerPoint 2011 from using ligatures in font?

Tags: mac, fonts

I'm working back and forth between Mac Powerpoint and Windows PowerPoint, and I think some problems are being introduced by the ligatures that the Mac automatically uses with its fonts (for example, linking the ti in any word that ends in "tion").  Is there a way to turn this off?